# Split and replace string with character

Tags: c#, split

I need to extract the values which are between the special characters `&`.

```
string text = "&2&LL&1&likk&3&";
```

I need to extract the value `2, 1, 3` and insert the corresponding index of the `List<string>`.

The list contains 10 elements:

```
0 - A
1 - B
2 - C
3 - D
...
9 - J
```

Finally when I substitute the list element to the string, it should be printed as **C**LL**B**likk**D**. How can I do this ?

I tried splitting as follow:But, It only splits using the & sign.

```
string[] xx = text.Split('&');
```

Comment: Can't you do just do a simple loop with a replace for `&i&` where `i` is the index of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        List<string> f = new List<string> ( ) { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
        string text = "&2&LL&1&likk&3&";
        for ( int i = 0; i < f.Count; i++ )
        {
            text = text.Replace ( i.ToString ( ), f[ i ] );
        }
        text=text.Replace ( "&", "" );
        Console.WriteLine ( text );
```

go through all the values in the list with a "FOR" and reasign the value of text with the value to replace

**EDITED**

```
        List<string> f = new List<string> ( ) { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
        string text = "&2&LL&1&likk&3&";
        for ( int i = 0; i < f.Count; i++ )
        {
            text = text.Replace ($"&{ i.ToString ( )}&", f[ i ] );
        }
        Console.WriteLine ( text );
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression alternative (17 is the difference from `'A' - '0'`) :

```
var result = Regex.Replace("&2&LL&1&likk&3&", "&[0-9]&", m => (char)(m.Value[1] + 17) + "");
```

Comment: that's great answer, but does it work for numbers greater than 9?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try something like this

```
 string text = "&2&LL&1&likk&3&";
        string[] xx = text.Split('&');
        string text2 = "";
        string[] abc = { "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J" };
        for (int i = 0; i < xx.Length; i++)
        {
            text2 += xx[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < abc.Length; i++)
        {
            text2 = text2.Replace(""+i, abc[i]);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(text2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use regular expressions to do this, because regex is fun!

&\d& will match all of the digits between & symbols. Considering you're implying that letters and numbers should map together, we can adopt Henocs answer to to use regex for bonus points!

```
List<string> f = new List<string> ( ) { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
    string text = "&2&LL&1&likk&3&";
    for ( int i = 0; i < f.Count; i++ )
    {
        text = text.RegexReplace ( text, "&" + i + "&", f[ i ] );
    }
    Console.WriteLine ( text );
```

By creating a regular expression of &(target digit)&, and replacing it with a letter from our string list, we will replace the entire block, rather than just the number.

Comment: please, check the edition of the answer, there replaced & + # + & by the value of the index in the list